# Is there a Odoo function list?

Tags: odoo

I was wondering if there is like a documentation(for odoo v8) off all functions in the Odoo code? that explains what they do.

Comment: Why are you asking here instead of asking Google? It's much faster.

Comment: i did ask google and was searching for about an hour, then i asked here a nd got an answer in like 10 min.

Comment: It took me 10 seconds to find the Odoo v8 manual: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference.html. It was in first 3 results on first page of Google search.

Comment: yeah but those are the main ones i was looking for one with all methods but as forvas told me i wont find one with all methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the section of the official website where some of the main methods of Odoo are explained:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html

Of course, those are only a few compared with all you can find in the code. You will not find a webpage which explains all methods. The best way to learn Odoo is working with modules as an user and then reading the code to know how they managed to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have [here](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/how-to/developers-13/what-documentation-is-available-for-odoo-60312) a bunch of links related to Odoo: documentation pages, blogs, tutorials... OpenERP 7 and 6 as well